# using jQuery's ajax in Opera(cross domain request)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, opera

I don't know if it is a bug in Opera, but it is really strange behavior.

When I use jQuery's **ajax** to send a request, Opera will say "No transport" error.

I notice that this is a cross domain request and opera prohibits this.

So how can I change this situation in Jquery?

Comment: As far as I know, Opera doesnt support Cross domain request. http://userscripts.org/topics/2026

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera doesn't support cross-origin XMLHttpRequests yet. You can either use JSONP (if you control the origin server for the data or they have a JSONP option) or detect the "no transport" error and show an error message to the website visitor. Opera 12 should support what you need, but try to avoid using browser detection to show the "not supported" message.